# SKScene in SwiftUI is not filling screen when orientation is changed

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swiftui, orientation

I have an SKScene which I am presenting in SwiftUI with the code below:

```
struct ContentView: View{


var scene: SKScene {
    let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
    
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    return scene
}

var body: some View {
    
            
    SpriteView(scene: scene)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to change the orientation of my device to work in landscape as well as portrait. In my GameScene class I add the following method within the initialiser statement:

```
UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
    //add the observer
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(orientationChanged(notification:)),
        name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification,
        object: nil)
```

and then add the following function within the GameScene class:

```
 @objc func orientationChanged(notification : NSNotification) {
    }
```

I can add a print statement to this and can confirm that this is correctly called every time the orientation is changed. My issue is that the view rotates, however does not properly update.  I have tried adding:

```
let screenSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
self.size = screen size
print(self.size)
```

If I observe my print line, I can determine that the size of my GameScene is being updated, however this is not displaying correctly on the device.  In reality it looks like my portrait view is just being rotated, and so the width is the central half of the screen, and the height goes off the edges of the device when in landscape mode.

I have tried changing .aspectFill in the SwiftUI code, but I cannot get this to behave correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead the following

```
var body: some View {
   
    GeometryReader { gp in
      SpriteView(scene: scene)
        .frame(width: gp.size.width, height: gp.size.height)
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

Comment: That was it! I shall do some research into GeometryReader, as I have not head of this

Comment: I have had a play, and this doesn't quite fulfil the requirements.  I could be wrong but this appears to reinitialise my SKScene each time the orientation changes.  If I add a spriteNode to my scene after init, rotating the device draws the initialised state of the screen

Comment: The `SpriteView(..)` will be created every time `body` is called, it does not depend of how orientation tracked - using `GeometryReader` is most valid SwiftUI way to handle orientation change. If you want (don't want) something recreated you have to do that manually.

Comment: Ah okay. So for me this is not a practical way, as there are a lot of modifications to the scene and additional sprites created after initialization. 
So this is where I do not know how to update the size. My code above shows that I can detect the orientation change, and redraw the current state of the scene. But the visible frame size does not seem to update.